# how to add images through reactjs and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

How send form data when submit button is click how send image to nodejs server
Please give me selection what should I change in this code.
Please help me what should I do.

```
handleProductImage(e) {
 this.props.updateProductImage(e.target.files[0])
 }
  handleAddProduct(){
   let formData = new FormData()
   formData.append('File', this.props.productImage[0])
    Axios({
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/api/ecommerce/product/add',
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
       },
      data: {
        productImage:formData,

      }
     }).then((response)=>{
       if (response.data.success){
         window.location.href = response.data.redirectTo
     } else {
        console.log("data not saved");
     }
    })
   render(){
      return(<FlatButton
              label="Choose an Image"
              labelPosition="before"
              style={styles.uploadButton}
              containerElement="label"
            >
              <input type="file"
                style={styles.uploadInput}
                value={this.props.productImage}
                onClick={this.handleProductImage}/>
            </FlatButton>
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually use `axios` library to make request to server. In `updateProductImage`

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);
axios.post(url, data).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: Please see the once my code. And then give me help. Thankx

Comment: Just `data: formData`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `fetch` with `form-data` to upload image/file easily if you are using es6

```
var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', ____file_here____)
data.append('user', 'hubot')

fetch('/api_url', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
.then() {
    /* your response here */
}
```

Comment: Watch out for browser compatibility of `FormData `. Is not really well supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: Please see the once my code. And then give me help. Thankx